# Trying to execute simple spring-boot application, getting an marker error,

Tags: spring-boot, m2eclipse, spring-tool-suite

says cannot be read or is not a valid ZIP file, /.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-web/4.3.11.RELEASE/spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar in project

[image: STS Error Screenshot]

**This may be a STS maven error, i tried the same with eclipse mars 2, it works fine .. not understanding where is the problem ..? need help ... thanks**

**pom.xml**

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.de.course</groupId>
<artifactId>course-api</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>course-api</name>
<description>Course API Data</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.7.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
        <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**project structure**

[image: project structure]

**Maven Dependencies folder from project**

[image]

[image: maven build]

Comment: i solve this issue by deleting .m2 folder, just maven updated can not solve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps jar is corrupted while downloading. Delete the jars from .m2 folder and update project from eclipse (`Maven -> Update project`). It should download deleted dependencies automatically.

Comment: thanks, @Yogesh its working fine...there was problem in dependency, i deleted .m2 folder, and its working fine .... thanks

Comment: Do not rely in eclipse for doing your maven stuff. The plugin sometimes files and it's better to use the maven command line tools for that.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be just an Eclipse refresh problem (if you've internet access, at least). Try `Project -> Clean` from the toolbar and right click in your project `Maven -> Update project`.

If the problem persists, try removing your project from Eclipse and reimporting it.

Anyway, sometimes Eclipse gets messy with the Maven dependencies. Because of that, I like having my own Maven installation in the system and running `mvn clean install` outside Eclipse to ensure the project gets properly built.

Comment: Even i tried to create spring-boot project with Spring Boot CLI, by spring boot initializer, by manually ... but still the same issue

Comment: Does it compile from outside eclipse? Try running maven from a console. Also check for the missing dependency in your .m2 folder. Does it exist?

Comment: yes, it exists in .m2 folder with the same path, where eclipse giving an error .... just check that too....

Comment: It might be that file being corrupted.. What about console? You could try right click in the project -> Run as.. Maven Build. Then, in the goals box write `clean install`.

Comment: its building properly .. i have updated my question with image, will you please check that

Comment: thanks .. @Xtreme Biker as you suggested, the dependency were corrupted. i deleted .m2 folder, and its working fine .... thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the spring-web dependency to your pom.xml
Add the following to the dependencies tag in your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.11.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: its spring-boot application, spring-web is not required to added manually, and jar is available in maven dependency folder. im adding image of it